# MySQL database design for a car parking garage

Tags: mysql, database

I recently recieved a project from a friend that has the following columns in excel

```
DATE | CAR TYPE | NUMBER PLATE | AMOUNT DUE | AMOUNT PAID | BALANCE | STATUS | TIME IN | TIMEOUT
```

- There are basically 3 car types ie CARS, VANS, TRUCKS
- Each Car type is charged a different fixed amount
- Amount due (is the amount charged after the day ends
- Amount paid is the amount that the car owner pays at the end of the day

I really need help creating the MySQL database and the relationships. I have a very partial clue on how to start and no material I have read here has been helpful so far. How can I convert this excel table into a functional MYSQL database with relations.

Comment: If you do not have a clue, you are definitely not in a position to provide a meaningful help to your friend.

Comment: you want a vehicle table where you store the vehicles and their type_id.. you would want a charges table with the amount due and paid and balance.. that would need to be linked to the vehicle table via ID in vehicle table and vehicle_id in the charges table... and then the time table i'm guessing for when it came in and left again linked to the vehicle table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something kinda like this is how I would set up the table

```
VEHICLE (`ID`, `TYPE_ID`, `PLATE`) 
VEHICLE_TYPE (`ID`, `TYPE`)
CHARGES (`ID`, `VEHICLE_ID`, `AMOUNT_DUE`, `AMOUNT_PAID`, `BALANCE`, `STATUS`)
TIME_OCCURRED (`ID`, `VEHICLE_ID`, `DATE`, `TIME_IN`, `TIME_OUT`)
```

the vehicle table has a unique id for each new vehicle, a type_id linked to the vehicle_type table. the type column would be a varchar for what type of vehicle.
the charges table would hold the info for all the charges due on each vehicle linked by the vehicle_id
and the time occurred would be the same..

not sure what the 'status' column is so if you can explain that I can put it in one of the tables.

to be honest... you need to do a lot more research before you're ready to take on a big assignment like this... it might be best to play with some smaller pieces of data first to be sure you get it working.

Comment: The STATUS is for the payments to show if the car owner has paid or not.

Comment: @PaulKin ok then it would go with the charges table.. you can call it whatever you want.. but I would do something kinda like that :)